# Remove element from list/dictionary efficiently and cleanly?

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity

Here is some sample code:

```
shopping = ["milk", "eggs", "bananas"]

# slower? uses 2 O(n) operations
if "milk" in shopping:
    shopping.remove("milk")
    print("milk removed from shopping list.")
else:
    print("milk not in shopping list, not removing.")

# faster? Only uses one O(n) operation, right?
try:
    shopping.remove("milk")
    print("milk removed from shopping list.")
except:
    print("milk not in shopping list, not removing.")
```

How do these two methods compare? Is one faster than the other? Would using a dictionary (hashmap) be even faster, as it would be O(1) to find the element (if a bit more memory-intensive (right?))?

Comment: If you want to use a hashmap-based structure, `set` is a better choice here, since you don't really have any "values" for a dictionary, only "keys". It should indeed on average be O(1) to remove an item from a set or dict.

Comment: There's some overhead in exception handling, but for lists of sufficient size, yes, one O(n) operation is faster than two. It is trivial to time both methods using `timeit` and prove it to yourself.

Comment: Yes, technically option 1 uses 2 O(n) operations, but unless your list contains thousands of items or you're calling this thousands of times the difference is gonna be inconsequential and it's better to focus on which code is more readable.

Comment: "*How do these two methods compare?*" See [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Keep in mind that constant factors matter. Big-O notation measures how things scale, but for small values of n, O(n) can be faster than O(n^3). In general, the Right Thing is to think about the needs of your data structures first in terms of what kinds of constraints you need (ordered/unordered?) and what kinds of operations you're going to perform (append? prepend? insert in arbitrary locations?) -- if you get in the habit of choosing the right structure for the job, or combining them appropriately if there _is_ no one right structure, performance will take care of itself.

Comment: Third option: Put an elephant in Cairo.

Comment: (Mind, for a lot of the thinking-about-what's-the-right-structure purposes, I generally consider `list.remove()` and other innately-inefficient things not to exist as options in the first place; but that's the general case -- for a shopping list, your `n` is bounded to be small enough that doing O(n) things is fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious so tested one scenario myself: Trying to remove "toast" from that list (which isn't in there). Results:

```
135.1 ± 1.1 ns  LBYL
220.9 ± 1.6 ns  elephant_in_Cairo
503.9 ± 2.1 ns  EAFP
522.0 ± 2.1 ns  EAFP2

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

Code:

```py
def LBYL(lst, value):
    if value in lst:
        lst.remove(value)
        pass # removed
    else:
        pass # not found

def EAFP(lst, value):
    try:
        lst.remove(value)
        pass # removed
    except:
        pass # not found

def EAFP2(lst, value):
    try:
        lst.remove(value)
        pass # removed
    except ValueError:
        pass # not found

def elephant_in_Cairo(lst, value):
    lst.append(value)
    lst.remove(value)
    if lst and lst[-1] is value:
        lst.pop()
        pass # removed
    else:
        pass # not found

funcs = LBYL, EAFP, EAFP2, elephant_in_Cairo

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys

lst = ["milk", "eggs", "bananas"]
value = "toast"

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e9 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ns '
for _ in range(100):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(lst, value), number=10000) / 10000
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVTNbtQwEL5w8lOMwmETlC7dVpUgUg6AyqmHnpAgjSJvM95aTezInqxYrfokXHqBO6_AY_A0-CfbHxYJBCRSHM-Mv-8bz2g-fRk2dKXV7e3nkcTBi-9PPrQo4Oz1-7O0s5TDmncjZgUD90gRtyAVOGc0-sdt5gZ7vcY0xt95Bm4tPIXobIMZO4vFzwFKEwg9qpYxz3_66u35Pj-Zzd9yfrzEgf6E9ej_08I7H3hqjDa_U4AdDldcUSNV84ZLo_fVeAF8GFC1DwX8WpYrmHMAV61fq4NFDdJGtMcZDXpI_6loYlSXFsrQOHm4yPg9yvdzctFG90CyR0kg-0EbmnbRY4mTtCQd4uTtkavc2Vtcs8lkN5Yxn10JVdLL7jrJIcHVyvp1yZV7bVKz2LAlJKS5pYQxT-SVbkUBVe30GxC-oUMGN6EKnt-mYld-H10RPIMFvgzx5OOtE4FtGuAqUWdVcVLX4YBBGo0DnG297JRsVpzMF-IGvn2Fbcgh2I6DTVmYMQ_aeFDD1QrTxeHhxP1Y3X0BfNbxxtKO98uWFyAetkoOauyXaEoH5cDgOYSf-_OT6l0nUcbuqKbEAmMO17gpw31MigYjFaW7G8pBzJtG8R6bJmMsOmcX6jwMlWKW-zLN12is1CqLI2aaNLuJ8wM)

Answer (score -5):

### yes, try-except would be faster.

The first script checks if the item is in the list, that's an extra check that would make it slower.

But with the second script, it removes it straight away without an extra check.

Comment: You're ignoring the (_very_ substantial) overhead of the exception itself, which for lists this short costs far more time than it saves.

Comment: Unless it's not there. `try-except` is not "free".